# What is Narcissa Malfoy and Dorea Potter's Boggart?

Tags: harry-potter

According to the original Harry Potter book, what are they most afraid of？

Comment: Wow... I thought I knew almost everything about Harry Potter... but I can't for the life of me remember, who Dorea Potter is... In addition: This is two questions in one. Please ask each question separately, multiple questions are not wanted here (who do you give the "accepted" tick, if one answers correctly for Narcissa and another one for Dorea)

Answer (score 4):

**Unknown and Unknown**

[**Dorea Potter** (née Black)](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Dorea_Black) is only seen in the Black and Potter family trees. Consequently, no information (including her boggart form) about her is known, aside from her parentage, who she married and her offspring.

---

**Narcissa Malfoy**'s [boggart form](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Boggart) isn't described in the Harry Potter novels or tie-in media, and hence is unknown.

As with all characters without a known Boggart form, her freeplay boggart in the  [Harry Potter Lego](https://youtu.be/oAJpXk9VRaU?t=213) games is Lord Voldemort.